Calling Google API from different service JSON one one server
I'm working on a project where I have multiple service account JSONs from different Google Cloud accounts. Using these JSONs, I need to call the Google Workspace API to make changes, such as updating settings. My concern is whether Google's policy allows API calls for multiple service accounts from the same server. If this is not permitted, are there any alternatives, like using a VPN or Cloudflare Durable Objects, to manage this?
I'd appreciate any insights or solutions, as I've searched online but haven't found a clear answer.
Thank you!

Where is hosted your server? On Google Cloud?
